# Home air quality monitor - adafruit request failed

Tags: python, upload, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

Hey I'm a complete Newbie to the whole Raspberry Pi universe and the last few days I tried to make my home air quality monitor work.
Yesterday I finally found a script to make the program run. here is my script:
aio = Client('Hallo','123456')

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')

while True:
data= []
for index in range (0,10):
datum = ser.read()
data.append(datum)

```
    pmtwofive = int.from_bytes(b''.join(data[2:4]), byteorder='little') / 10
    aio.send('python3 airquality.py', pmtwofive)
    pmten = int.from_bytes(b''.join(data[4:6]), byteorder='little') / 10
    aio.send('airquality.py', pmten)
    time.sleep (10)
```

When I try to run this script there occurs the following error:

(most recent call last):
File "/home/teamplazer/airquality.py", line 15, in 
aio.send('python3 airquality.py', pmtwofive)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 167, in send_data
return self.create_data(feed, payload)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 313, in create_data
return Data.from_dict(self._post(path, data._asdict()))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 139, in _post
self._handle_error(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 117, in _handle_error
raise RequestError(response)
Adafruit_IO.errors.RequestError: Adafruit IO request failed: 404 Not Found - not found - that is an invalid URL, please check the API documentation at https://io.adafruit.com/api/docs to make sure your URL is correct

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
I appreciate your thoughts and your time! Thank you for helping me!